# Thymleaf I18N Syntax

Tags: thymeleaf

I have this code;

```
<div class="row">
        <h5 th:text="#{heading.st}"/>
        <h6 th:text="${'Sub Type: ' + results[0].subType + '; Internal Switch Role: ' + results[0].internalSwitch}"></h6>
 </div>
```

where `#{heading.st}` is the internationalized string for 'Sub Type' stored in a properties file. So I can see than i18n is correctly set up. However, I cannot workout the syntax for replacing the string `Sub Type` in the h6 element. Both

```
<h6 th:text="${#heading.st + ': ' + results[0].subType + '; Internal Switch Role: ' + results[0].internalSwitch}"></h6>
```

and
    
give syntax errors. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more options as well.  Personally, my favorite is either using [literal substitutions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions):

```
<h6 th:text="|#{heading.st}: ${results[0].subType}|" />
```

or using additional tags like this:

```
<h6>
    <span th:text="#{heading.st}" />: <span th:text="${results[0].subType}" />
</h6>
```

I think either option is more readable than string concatenation.

Comment: I hadn't come across literal substitutions before, so thanks for that. And I agree, it's easier to read than concatenation, and easier to type too.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
<h6 th:text="#{heading.st} + ': ' + ${results[0].subType}"></h6>
```